AWS Cognito authoriser gives 403 error with the valid token
I created Cognito authoriser for API Gateway and seems it throw 403 error when use the real token. I have tested this using test utility which comes with api gateway authoriser itself.
Created both ID token and user token using Cognito UI with the valid user. But seems the token is invalid. Anyone got same experience with auth errors when using Cognito authoriser?

Which token did you try? AFAIK cognito authorizer validates only ID token by default. If you want to use access toke, you need to add custom scopes to your token. But that will incur extra costs. However you can use custom lambda authorizer.

Agree, try using ID Token. Use access token when you are using custom scopes. I don’t think using custom scopes incurs additional cost.

I had same issue with ID token and access token. When you try the test utility, you need to use ID token and when you use a client like postman, then you need to use the access token. little bit confusing.
This is a good explanation (Cognito Authoriser): https://youtu.be/9crTLAT_4uY
This is for Lambda authorizer: https://youtu.be/rRQbVJhlpC4

I had this issue, was giving me the same 403 error, tried idtoken and access token both in test, then I just deployed the API with this authoriser and tried access token first for the deployed API (this did not work), and then I tried idToken(and it gave me 200 response) , and then when I tried idToken for testing it gave me back proper response with 200 code.
